# Не вызывается запрос о permission в android 6.0+

Tags: android, permissions

Необходимо разрешение на чтение External Storage. Вот гист как я это делаю:

[Гист](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f97243834a8d9ee15dde7c5384a13d30)

Но проблема в том, что во время выполнения оно игнорирует. В манифесте тоже прописал.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Не понимаю, что не так...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй android.permissions_group.STORAGE для 6.0 и выше, либо дополнительно запрашивай "android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

Comment: android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - Помогло) Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

В Android 6.0 появились Runtime Permission.

А начиная с этой версии некоторое зависимости нужно не только описать в манифесте, но и запросить разрешение на них во время исполнения программы.

Официальная документация:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
Статья на русском:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/